# Do published packages take priority over workspaces when running npm install?

Tags: npm, npm-install

I have a monorepo project and I'm migrating to `npm@7`. Before npm workspaces, I had to publish packages to a private feed and then consume them in my app (I didn't bother with `npm link` shenanigans). Not ideal, but I made do.

Then npm introduced workspaces, and now I'm trying to migrate. While resolving peer dependency conflicts, I noticed that when I made changes to any package.json files, `npm install` would return the same errors unless I updated package versions to something that hadn't been published yet. I wasn't expecting this kind of behavior.

So how does npm determine where to search for a package first? Does `npm install` download packages from the registry *before* looking at workspaces? Is this intentional, and if so, why?